# Publishing failed for the Master Page in SDL Tridion 2009

Tags: publishing, 2009

I have a problem with publishing in SDL Tridion 2009 web site managament. When I am publishing the Master page (in order to publish all the subfolder elements) it shows a failed status in the publishing queue.

The pages seems to be successfully published but the master page is failed, so the changes of the pages doesnt appear on the website. The context of the problem is:

> JScriptException: Expression 'GetImageAlt("tcm:70-1386")' had error 'Variable 'GetImageAlt' has not been declared'.

The TCM address in the error message, is from our corporation logo. What should I do to fix this problem and publish successfully?

Answer (score 6):

You seem to be missing one of the function sources.

You should find a dll which contains the function `GetImageAlt` and add it to the GAC. After, you need to add a reference to this dll into the `functionSources` section of your `Tridion.ContentMananger.config`. See an example snippet of the `Tridion.ContentMananger.config` below:

```xml
<tridion.templating>
  <functionSources>
    <functionSource type="Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.Expression.BuiltInFunctions" />
    <functionSource type="MyCustomClass" assembly="MyCustomClass, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ddfc8957d6e5ee6b" />
  </functionSources>
</tridion.templating>
```

Comment: this is the answer which pops up to my mind as soon as I saw question.

Answer (score 3):

In case that the DLL containing function GetImageAlt is specified in the Tridion.ContentManager.config and that it is registered in GAC, verify that it has been registered for the correct .NET Framework version (on which your SDL Tridion CM is running).

The GAC location and the executable to register DLLs in GAC is different for different .NET Framework version and in case of mismatch, though they shows registered successfully, it actually does not.